# @AfterReturning(pointcut) not reached

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, backend

I have a method to determine what action is done on a field (edited,deleted,etc.), when that method is executed I want to store an audit file of what happened. The method executes fine and returns `action`, but it will not reach the `@AfterReturning`. Anyone know why that's the case?

This is the code of the method:

```
public Action determineUpdateAction(BirthRegistration existingBirthRegistration, BirthRegistrationField updatedBirthRegistrationFieldDetails, Action action) {
        if(checkPreviousBirthRegistrationDetails(existingBirthRegistration, updatedBirthRegistrationFieldDetails)) {
            action = Action.ADDED;
        } else if (StringUtils.isBlank(updatedBirthRegistrationFieldDetails.getValue())) {
            action = Action.DELETED;
        }
        return action;
    }
```

This is the code of the audit event:

```
@AfterReturning(pointcut = "execution(* com.test.app.*.service.DefaultBirthRegistrationService.determineUpdateAction(..)) && args(existingBirthRegistration, updatedBirthRegistrationFieldDetails, action)")
    public void editEvent(BirthRegistration existingBirthRegistration, Action action, BirthRegistrationField updatedBirthRegistrationFieldDetails) {
        audit(existingBirthRegistration.getReferenceNumber(), action, updatedBirthRegistrationFieldDetails.getName());

    }
```

I have tried adding `return="action"` after declaring the pointcut, but then the app won't start.

Comment: Need more information in the question regarding your code that fails. Following are to be made sure 1. `determineUpdateAction()` is a Spring bean method 2. `editEvent()` method should be in a class that is annotated with `@Aspect` and should be a spring bean. If you can share the complete java code for both these classes , it would help us help you

Comment: @R.G I have more @AfterReturning methods in the same class that do work, it's only this one that's failing. As for the ``determineUpdateAction()``, this one is called inside another method, could this be the problem?

Comment: yes that is the problem. Self invocation ( internal call ) cannot be intercepted

Comment: Please read through the section in [reference documenation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-pointcuts-designators) . *Due to the proxy-based nature of Spring’s AOP framework, calls within the target object are, by definition, not intercepted*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As R.G. mentioned, this was not possible since `determineUpdateAction()` was called inside another method.